# Game image assets doesn't fit window size

Tags: c#, forms, image, game-development

I'm creating a simple 2d scrolling game as my school project on C#, but I cant seem to find the ratio between the background (platform) and the form height.
here's what I'm trying to do, my form height is 1080, and all of my pictures height are 2160px (double the form) with dpi of 96, I have the background, the floor, and the hero all on different image files so that I can move each one as I want.
I'm trying to get them all to start from the bottom so it would look like this [image: how it's supposed to look]

so I write this code.

```
void Start()
{
  flag = 's';
  bg = new Bitmap("bg.bmp");
  pf = new Bitmap("platform.png");
  player = new Bitmap("idle.png");
  y = -(pf.Height-this.ClientSize.Height);
  mmy = y;
  DrawDubBuff(this.CreateGraphics());   
}
void DrawScen(Graphics g)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        //SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        //g.FillRectangle(br, this.Width/2 - this.Height/4, 0, (this.Height/2), this.Height);
        if (flag=='m')
        {
            g.DrawImage(bg, x, y);
            g.DrawImage(menu, this.Width/2, this.Height/2);

        }
        else if (flag == 's')
        {
            g.DrawImage(bg, x, y);
            g.DrawImage(pf, pfx, y);
            g.DrawImage(player, mmx, mmy);
            //Color pixel = pf.GetPixel(mmx, mmy+10);
            MessageBox.Show(""+pf.Height+", "+ this.ClientSize.Height);
            //if (pixel.A == 0)
            //{
            //    mmy--;
            //}
        }
    }

    void DrawDubBuff(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(off);
        DrawScen(g2);
        g.DrawImage(off, 0, 0);
    }
```

but it ends up looking like this
[image]

the red square is exactly at half the image size (1080)
even when I change the image size to 1080 and make y=0, it still doesnt fit the form, it always goes beyond the screen size. I spent hours searching but I couldn't find anything that helped. really hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance ~

UPDATE
this is what happens when I set y=-1080
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, 0,0 on a winforms/GDI canvas is top left, try setting y to 1080 rather than 0

Comment: its a black screen when I do that, nothing shows, the whole image goes beyond the screen.
I tried setting it to -1080  tho, so it's supposed to have the end of the image start at (0,0) but it shows the image finishing at y=165